# Two coils - inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

Let's say we have two coils, A and B. Suppose there's AC flowing in coil A. The changing current generates a changing magnetic field, and it induces some current in coil B. That's what we know. My question is, if the induced current in coil B is a changing current, does it produce some changing magnetic field as well that will induce a SEM in coil A?

Answer (score 0):

Coil B will have an emf induced in it, but there will be a current in it only if it is part of a complete circuit. It will then, as you suggest, produce an alternating magnetic field, and that will induce an emf in coil A. The emf in the circuit of which A is part will then be the phasor sum of three alternating emfs: the 'source' emf, the emf induced in A by changing flux due to the current in A changing, and the emf you were asking about!